# Cassandra exception while live schema change

Tags: cassandra

For our project we need live schema changes. For these purposes we created test. It  adds and deletes tables in cassandra. `I'm using 10 threads with datastax driver. But I am getting this Exception in some threads`.

> Exception in thread "Thread-7"
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException:  All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException:  Timeout during
>   read))

Cassandra is alive. I can still execute queries throw cqlsh. 
Threads does'n fail. Thread can add tables, then suddenly log this exception and again add tables. Exception can appear several times in one thread.
Each thread has its own session.

Looking to the **cassandra.yaml**:

```
concurrent_writes and reads = 32
```

increasing of `MAX_HEAP_SIZE and HEAP_NEWSIZE in cassandra-env.sh doesn't help me`.

Cassandra version 2.0.7

Could someone suggest how to deal with it?

```
public class AddTableThread extends Thread {

    private Cluster cluster;
    private Session session;

    private final String KEYSPACE = "cas";
    private final String HOST = "localhost";
    private final int PORT = 9042;

    private boolean isRunning = true;

    // counter for the added tables
    private int i = 0;

    // Number of the tables that thread has to add
    private int fin = -2;

    public AddTableThread() {
        connect();
    }

    public AddTableThread setTablesCount(int f) {
        this.fin = f;
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " : must add " + fin + " tables");
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println(this.getName() + " : starting thread \n");

        while (isRunning) {
            String name = createName();
            try {

                session.execute(createTableQuery(name));

                System.out.println(this.getName() + " : table is created "
                        + name);
                i++;
            } catch (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException e) {
                System.out
                        .println("\n\n" + this.getName() + "!!!!FAILED!!!!!!");
                System.out.println(this.getName() + " : added " + i + " tables");
                System.out.println(this.getName() + " : table " + name
                        + " wasn't added");
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep((new Random().nextInt(5000)));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (i == fin) {
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }
        close();
        log();
    }

    // creates query that creates table in keyspace with name tableName
    private String createTableQuery(String tableName) {
        return "CREATE TABLE cas." + tableName
                + "(id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY, text varchar, value int);";
    }

    public void finish() {
        isRunning = false;

    }

    private void log() {
        System.out.println("\n" + this.getName() + " : finish");
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " : added " + i + " tables");
        System.out.println("_____________________\n");
    }

    // generates unique table name
    private String createName() {
        return "cf_" + UUIDGen.getTimeUUID().toString().replace("-", "_");
    }

    private void connect() {
        SocketOptions so = new SocketOptions();
        so.setConnectTimeoutMillis(20000);
        so.setReadTimeoutMillis(20000);

        cluster = Cluster.builder().withSocketOptions(so).addContactPoint(HOST)
                .withPort(PORT).build();
        session = cluster.connect(KEYSPACE);
    }

    private void close() {
        session.close();
        cluster.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Tanya, Did you find a solution for this. We too are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Creating takes time. So try to increment:

> read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000

and

> request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

And try to uncomment

> rpc_max_threads: 2048

Experiment with these parameters.

Comment: I just tried to play with these parameters but that doesn't help

Comment: Say me, please: has datastax driver some config-settigs for connect timeout, read timeout,..? Try to see in this direction. Maybe client disconnects before reading response from Cassandra.

Comment: Every thread connects to cassandra ones. However, it creates tables after exception. Why the session is still alive? I built cluster with connectTimeOut 20s and the same readTimeout. first, i thought that all is ok. But when too many tables were added, the error repeated. I cleared db and increase the number of the threads. And exception appears again... Seems like it's some memory false

Comment: Please, post your source code somewhere. Татьяна, пожалуйста, разместите где-нибудь используемый Вами исходный код.

Comment: Tanya, I haven't got any problems with your code. So, I don't know what to suggest you. Maybe you need to try some other driver... Astyanax, Hector,.. I used your code with very small changes and Cassandra 2.0.6. You may download all from here (IntelliJ IDEA project and Cassandra): https://cloud.mail.ru/public/8ae32ec183a1/Tanya.rar

Comment: Dmitry, i just tried to run with your versions, that doesn't work for me. But thanks for your reply